# Reverse routing in buffalo

Tags: go, buffalo

Is there any possibility to use a reverse router, e.g. similiar to the Play framework? This would be helpful in order not to hardcode URLs outside the app.go.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're looking for? I suspect many (such as myself) don't know what Play framework is, so won't be able to provide an answer based on your current description.

Comment: Buffalo's router is a wrapper over gorilla/mux, but AFAIK it doesn't expose gorilla/mux's reverse routing functionality.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton, you pointed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

In app.go use Name() to define a name for the route (as in mux). For example:

```
auth.GET("/{provider}", bah).Name("login")
```

buffalo will however append "Path" to it and make it available as

```
loginPath({key : value})
```

for example:

```
<a href="<%= loginPath({provider: "github"}) %>">login</a>
```

Comment: I will leave this open for now, maybe somebody else can give a better answer.